# How do I get a String from a loop which runs in a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I started converting my code to a more object oriented style and now I'm having some problems. I'm running a while loop which returns messages received from a socket.

```
public void run(){

    try {

        while(IrcMessage != null){

        IrcMessage = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(IrcMessage);
        ....
        ....
```

I want those messages to be displayed in my jframe. I do have an idea how this could work but I dont know how to execute it. How do I access a variable declared in a thread?

```
public class socketRead extends Thread{

    String IrcMessage = "";
```

Where I start my thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    NewJFrame frame = new NewJFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.read.start();        
}
```

I hope you get my question. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want your thread return value use Callable instead of Runable.

Comment: Returning from thread is tricky. Like @ASdi suggested you should use Callable. Another alternative used in some cases is defining your variable 'Volatile'.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I will look up for Callable and try my best.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a reference to your `JFrame` to the thread which needs to update it.